# How Should I Store Data for My Android App?

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, storage

I'm quite new to Android programming (very little programming experience). I want to make an app that will track Car maintenance. I would like users to be able to see their data (roughly) according to the following hierarchy:

Year (see total costs, maybe summarize categories)
--Month (month's costs)
----Maintenance Instance
------Details about the instance (what was done for what cost)

I don't have my data design finalized, but you can see the kind of data I'm trying to track. What approach would you suggest? Do I need to use SQLite? If so, would you recommend a hierarchy of tables or just one table that will be shown hierarchically through queries? Like I said, I'm new.  I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store simple data like global preferences (i.e. in your app you could store a currency flag as a preference to display currency as dollars or pounds) but for anything more complicated you should use SQLite. This tutorial is excellent and will get you started - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html It seems like you could have one table with each row being a maintenance entry with columns for the date, cost and action carried out. You could then query the database by a date range to get the cost for that range or a list of action carried out in that range (e.g. per month or year). Each row would represent a separate maintenance event.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use JSON, a very easy to use storage format. A typical JSON message you would store might look like the following:

```
{
    "maintenance_data": [
        {
          "date": 1091029109,
          "maintenance_details": "Drove car around while owner was gone"
        },
        {
          "date": 1021234134,
          "maintenance_details": "Ate cookies while on job"
        },
        {
          "date": 1041023234,
          "maintenance_details": "Ain't nobody got time for maintenance"
        }
        ],

        "car_id": 1234,
        "owner_name": "Slick diddy"
}
```